# Why is the window resize event appending the g element repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

While I am trying to resize the events with D3, it is showing that the element "g" which I am appending in the chart is printing repeatedly during resize. How can I use the `this` keyword? Or something like that?
[This is the code on js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/js1r6aow/).

**Question:** How can I solve it with the `this` keyword in d3?

```
function redraw(){
    let chartContainer = document.getElementById("bar_Chart");
    let containerWidth = chartContainer.clientWidth;
    let containerHeight = chartContainer.clientHeight;


    let inputData = [
        {name: "JAN", value:  10},
        {name: "FEB", value:  8},
        {name: "MAR", value: 15},
        {name: "APR", value: 16},
        {name: "MAY", value: 23},
        {name: "JUN", value: 30},
        {name: "JUL", value: 12},
        {name: "AUG", value: 41},
        {name: "SEP", value: 52},
        {name: "OCT", value: 23},
        {name: "NOV", value: 32},
        {name: "DEC", value: 42}
    ];

    let margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    let width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    let height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        let x = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .padding(0.1);

    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    let tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");


    let chart = d3.select(".chart-svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    x.domain(inputData.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(inputData, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)



    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)


    chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(inputData)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0.85)
                .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
                .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px");
            tooltip
                .style("display", "inline-block")
                .html((d.name) + "£" + (d.value));
            d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(300)
            .style("fill", "red");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0);
            tooltip
                .style("display", "none");
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .style("transition", "scale(1.8)");
        });

    }


    redraw();
    window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first draw your graph you need to call `enter` to bind your data to DOM elements and `append` to create the DOM elements. When you resize the window, you don't want to call `enter` or `append` anymore because the data is already bound to the DOM elements and the DOM elements already exist. All you really want to do is adjust the size of things with `attr` and to setup your axes again.

You could have 2 functions `draw` and `redraw` which is the same as `draw` except that it doesn't call `enter` or `append`. I show them here:

```
let inputData = [
    {name: "JAN", value:  10},
    {name: "FEB", value:  8},
    {name: "MAR", value: 15},
    {name: "APR", value: 16},
    {name: "MAY", value: 23},
    {name: "JUN", value: 30},
    {name: "JUL", value: 12},
    {name: "AUG", value: 41},
    {name: "SEP", value: 52},
    {name: "OCT", value: 23},
    {name: "NOV", value: 32},
    {name: "DEC", value: 42}
];

let margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40};

function draw() {
    let chartContainer = document.getElementById("bar_Chart"); 
    let containerWidth = chartContainer.clientWidth; 
    let containerHeight = chartContainer.clientHeight;

    let width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    let height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    let x = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .padding(0.1);

    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    let tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    let chart = d3.select(".chart-svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    x.domain(inputData.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(inputData, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(inputData)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0.85)
                .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
                .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px");
            tooltip
                .style("display", "inline-block")
                .html((d.name) + "£" + (d.value));
            d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(300)
            .style("fill", "red");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0);
            tooltip
                .style("display", "none");
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .style("transition", "scale(1.8)");
        });
}

function redraw() { 
    let chartContainer = document.getElementById("bar_Chart"); 
    let containerWidth = chartContainer.clientWidth; 
    let containerHeight = chartContainer.clientHeight;
    let width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    let height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    let x = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .padding(0.1);

    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    let tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    let chart = d3.select(".chart-svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    x.domain(inputData.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(inputData, function (d) { return d.value; })]);

    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    chart.select(".x.axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)

    chart.select(".y.axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(inputData)
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', draw);
window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);
```

There is still a problem. The X direction scales nicely with the width of the window, but the Y direction does not. I believe you shouldn't be using `let containerHeight = chartContainer.clientHeight;` in the `redraw` function as it is not correctly calculating the height of the container element (it increases whether the window grows or shrinks). I'll leave this for you to fix. I played around with `window.innerHeight` instead and that seems to work better but its calculating the height of the window, not the container div.

Comment: can you please edit this in this ? and give me the link? https://jsfiddle.net/Towhid/y9s2xuke/

Comment: can you please fix the issue? please help me out. its a great trouble i am trying this from last night.